# I am writing code for CFD 3D solver ,program runs for small size of 3d matrix but it shows segmentation fault for large size

Tags: c++, c, arrays, 3d

I define arrays in this way:

```
double uo[n+2][m+2][n1+2] , 
       vo[n+2][m+2][n1+2] , 
       wo[n+2][m+2][n1+2] ,
       du[n+2][m+2][n1+2] , 
       dv[n+2][m+2][n1+2] ,
       dw[n+2][m+2][n1+2] ,  
       w1[n+2][m+2][n1+2] , 
       z1[n+2][m+2][n1+2] ,
       z[n+2][m+2][n1+2]  ;
```

Once I made it as `static double` then error removes but it keeps running and does not terminate.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` or `n` are to big, you'll get a `stackoverflow` because you are trying to take to much space in your stack.
Dynamic allocation should be done in the heap using functions such as `malloc()`